# upgrade GStreamer in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

I want to upgrade my GStreamer (1.14) to 1.18.

If I use apt-get install, it does not give me 1.18.

So is the only way to upgrade is by building it myself?

Furthermore, when I try to uninstall the apt installed GStreamer by apt-get purge autoremove gstreamer1.0, it seems that many os packages will be removed too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading your Ubuntu. Then you will get some newer release of GStreamer. There won't be major version upgrades through a life-cycle of a pinned distribution version.

Else you need to build GStreamer yourself. But beware as you have noticed a lot of other applications depends on GStreamer. So you will need to install as separate install and not replace you system version of GStreamer as you may break things if you do.